# Automatically move folders based on file name?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have about 1500 folders that I need to organize automatically via command line.

I'm looking for a way to search for all folders that contain `/lib/file.php` - if `file.php` does exist in the `lib` folder, I need the root folder (one level above lib) move into a new directory.

I know how to search for all folders containing `/lib/file.php` but can't figure out how to move them automatically into a new folder.  For example, if `/test123/lib/file.php` exists, then the `test123` folder should be moved into a new folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *pipe* chain of `find`, `sed`, `xargs` and `mv`

```
find -type f -wholename '*/lib/file.php' | sed 's:/lib/file\.php$::' | xargs -I dirs mv dirs /path/to/new/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
for d in *
do
  if [[ -r "${d}/lib/file.php" ]]
  then
    mv "${d}" "/some/new/place/."
  fi
done
```